# Is entropy a function of time?

Tags: cosmology, entropy, arrow-of-time

Is entropy a function of time?

Since universe is expanding with time (entropy increases) and contracting on reversal of time. Can we say entropy somehow related with time in addition to state?

Answer (score 2):

This depends on the system. For example, the Sackur-Tetrode equation gives the entropy of an ideal gas (i.e. no interactions, three dimensions, point particles) as,

$$S = N k_B \left[\log \frac{V}{N\lambda^3} + \frac52 \right]$$

in terms of the thermal wavelength, $\lambda$. Thus, if any of the variables which the entropys depends on, such as the volume, number of particles or their mass change over time, then so does $S$.

Since classically, entropy is not directly measurable, only entropy *differences*, in such cases the entropy necessarily changes, and thus is time dependent.

Answer (score 1):

By some definitions, time is defined in terms of [entropy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entropy_(arrow_of_time)).

In a standard sense, how can it be uncorrelated to time?